# Predicate Logic with Nobody

Tags: predicate-logic

Nobody is a college student and not smart. 
How does this translate into predicate logic? 
I am stuck between two:

¬∃x[person’(x) ∧ student’(x) ∧ ¬smart’(x)]

¬∃x[[person’(x) ∧ student’(x)]  → ¬smart’(x)]

Thanks!

Comment: Where did ambitious come from? It is not in the statement you are translating...

Comment: Sorry! I was saying something else when typing, but what if it was a word like smart instead? Am I close?

Comment: Plot twist: “Nobody” is actually a name.

Answer (score 2):

The first translation is the accurate one of the original English statement.

The second "translation" is actually false (even assuming the English statement is true): consider an $x$ that is not a person, or an $x$ who is not a student, or an $x$ who is a smart student—all of these are examples showing that the negated-existential is false.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you!